# Schema.describeTabs() returns empty DescribeTabSetResult

Tags: apex, schema

I have a piece of Apex code that does `Schema.describeTabs()`

When i run this as System Administrator, i get the tabs back just fine.

Some other users running this code get empty `List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult>`.

I can't find any specific permission requirements for querying this in the documentation :(

**Update** The user in question is a Salesforce Platform user (license wise), the Standard Salesforce user can get tab set result just fine

Comment: Adding as a comment : `I believe there is a profile setting for this Custom App Settings, only if its visible here, the user would be able to query for it`. As it was not a helpful answer.

Answer (score -1):

I tested the code using 'Developer Console > Debug > Open Execute Anonymous Window > Enter Apex Code' and it seemed to work here.

```
String appName = 'Sales';
List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult> resultList = Schema.describeTabs();

for(Schema.DescribeTabSetResult result : resultList){
    if(result.getLabel() == appName){
        System.debug('Description of the app: ' + result.getDescription());
        System.debug('Number of tabs in the tab: ' + result.getTabs().size());
        System.debug('Logo URL: ' + result.getLogoUrl());
    }
}

//DEBUG:
//Description of the app: The world's most popular sales force automation (SFA) solution
//Number of tabs in the tab: 15
//Logo URL: https: xxxxxx
```

Comment: this works because you have a full license. As I pointed out, this doesn't work for `PLATFORM` license, not full license.

Comment: Got it, thanks, I've been trying for a while.